# What is the science-fiction tradition of flying cars having their wheels turned sideways?

Tags: history-of, back-to-the-future

The DeLorean in Back to the Future turns its wheels sideways when it is about to fly. Also, there are many children's toys that feature similar concepts, such as this Lego kit, which features two such vehicles:

[image]

What was the first sci-fi story that used this idea? Did BTTF invent it, or has this been around longer? And why would sideways wheels be a good idea in the first place?

Comment: as to why they have sideways wheels alot of the cars that use them have the hover/flying mechanics in the wheel and so facing down it is the propulsion unit. some have jets in the back, and use the wheels to stabilize, others have all of that stuff just underneath the car, but the wheels themselves being part of what makes the car fly is prevalent.

Comment: @Himarm It seems like putting the flying stuff in the wheels is just retconning why the wheels are sideways. Why would you put the flying stuff in the wheels?

Comment: where else would you put the flying stuff you have to have something on the bottom of the car to at least keep it afloat and the wheels are the optimal place to put it, instead of on the bottom of the car where you already have all the car crap.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Because if you can put them anywhere, why not? You have to have wheels anyway if you want it to function as a regular car, so you can reuse space and it seems like the wheels would be relatively well positioned to function as thrusters to provide lift, too.

Comment: Don't amphibious car's wheels usually turn sideways? I know I've seen it in an early James Bond movie, Roger Moore early. Could have been picked up there?

Comment: The real question is, how do you lift the car enough to give the wheels room to slide sideways?

Comment: @Daft - You're thinking of [this](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Lotus_Esprit_S1_(1976)) amphibious car from *The Spy Who Loved Me* in 1977, but the wheels don't actually turn sideways, they retract into the car's body and there are separate fins that take their place. In any case this was after the SHIELD car from the 1965 comic that Freighra pointed to.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Damn. eh... I mean no, the one I was thinking of came out in 1964... the wheels did indeed turn sideways and acted as propulsion! And was faster and more fuel efficient than Freighra's suggestion too! Just don't ask for any references to it or evidence of it's existence in any way.. :D

Comment: Of all the things already on the outside of a car, wheels look the most like turbines. This is a very small mystery.

Comment: Out of universe, it's a very strong visual clue that the vehicle is operating in a different mode. Having the car up in the air with the wheels in their normal positions just doesn't look as cool.

Comment: If the wheels are horizontal and protruding from the chassis of the car, they can serve as bumpers. You're more likely to brush up against the outside wall of a building if you're at the height of the 10th floor and there's no curb (or pedestrians) between you and it.

Comment: @Daft Or if you meant [real life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibious_vehicle), the wheels don't move at all

Comment: @Izkata nope, Hypnosifl was correct.

Comment: Also out of universe, but having the source of lift in the wheels means you still get the benefit of the car's suspension.  Cars are designed to have the entirety of their weight supported by the wheels

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the 1964 novel [Chitty-Chitty-Bang-Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitty-Chitty-Bang-Bang), by Ian Fleming (yes, the guy that also brought us James Bond) the car actually does have the wheels turn flat to create a hovercraft effect for traveling over water:

CCBB, Ch. 6 *Marooned*:

> And do you know what? I bet you can’t guess! All four wheels, pointing
>   fore and aft as all car wheels do, had turned and had now flattened
>   out like a hovercraft! Being an inventor, Commander Pott realized what
>   this meant and what the result would be, so he pressed slowly on the
>   accelerator and, just as the waves came up level with the floorboards,
>   all four wheels began to turn like propellers. There was a jerk and
>   CHITTY-CHITTY-BANG-BANG began to move through the water, just like a
>   motor-boat, with the four wheels whizzing round and round propelling
>   her forward.
>
> Well, that was all very fine, but she was a heavy car with four people
>   in her and the only way to keep from sinking was to go so fast that
>   they were almost skimming over the surface. So Commander Pott trod the
>   accelerator into the floorboards, there was a great whirl of spray
>   from the four wheels, and CHITTY-CHITTY-BANG-BANG fairly sped across
>   the surface of the sea, kicking up a big bow wave like a speed-boat.

Comment: I'd quite forgotten about Chitty-Chitty Bang-Bang!  Good call

Comment: I had wondered if the original novel might have something like that.  Now I'm wondering if Fleming and Lee/Kirby came up with it independently, Lee/Kirby got the horizontal wheel idea from Fleming, or if there's something even further back they both drew from.  Technically, Chitty's not actually *flying* at that point, of course, but the adjusting wheels seem like the important part of the whole thing.

Answer (score 62):

The earliest such car that I am aware of is from the 1965 issue of Strange Tales that introduced SHIELD and inducted Nick Fury into their ranks.  You can see in the images on [this page](http://comicbook.com/blog/2013/10/02/agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-lolas-internal-workings/) that the wheels turn sideways and function as jet engines.

[image]

Comment: So in 1965 the notion was that the tires doubled as fans. That at least makes some sense.

Comment: I'm aware of only two earlier flying cars that actually look like normal cars when on the ground (rather than having giant airplane attachments or the like).  The Absent-Minded Professor's Model T, and Chitty-Chitty-Bang-Bang.  Neither has adjusting wheels.

Comment: Yes and if memory serves, on both of those cars the wheels kept on turning (why?!) even when flying.

Comment: Likely they kept spinning because whatever the mechanism that allowed flight, probably needed to keep the engine running. As an aside, children might have thought it strange for the car to be in motion but not have the wheels move. As an autistic child, such things would have been immediately noticeable to me.

Comment: @Thaddeus Well, the Professor's car HAD no engine (it was powered by a thrust-based system that explicitly broke Newton's laws of motion), but then he probably disconnected the transmission as well so it's likely they were just rotating from momentum and/or aerodynamic forces.

Comment: Perhaps the spinning wheels function as gyroscopic stabilizers.

Comment: FWIW, [@Roger](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22493/roger)'s question from his comment on the question, "The real question is, how do you lift the car enough to give the wheels room to slide sideways?", *has* been thought of by this comic designer.

Comment: "And do you know what? I bet you can’t guess! All four wheels, pointing fore and aft as all car wheels do, had turned and had now flattened out like a hovercraft!" Chitty-Chitty-Bang-Bang, ch6 (1964)

Comment: I would quit thinking of the wheels/tires here as "propellers" or "jet engines" and more like repulsors, ala Tony Stark and Ironman.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the wheels also function like a magnetic top (electrons' quantum angular momentum): for stable levitation? Though use at 45 and 90 degrees wasn't reported until 2012 and 2014. [1]

> Already in 1842, British mathematician Samuel Earnshaw proved that there is no stable configuration of levitating permanent magnets. If one magnet is levitated above another, the smallest disturbance will cause the system to crash. The magnetic top, a popular toy, circumvents the Earnshaw theorem: When it is disturbed, the gyrating motion of the top causes a system correction and stability is maintained. [2]

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-stabilized_magnetic_levitation

[2] https://phys.org/news/2017-10-nanomagnets-levitate-quantum-physics.html

Answer (score -1):

*This answer is speculative, but I'm posting it as an answer and not a comment in the hopes that it will generate some discussion.*

Why go sideways at all? Because it makes it look and feel more like a flying machine than just a car in the air.

First of all, it's potentially more aerodynamic. Look at the LEGO set: the wheels don't just flatten, they actually fold under the vehicle. It's certainly better for flying dynamics to not have wheel wells exposed, and it probably also helps with steering and balance to prevent the wheels from rotating freely.

Second, we're used to seeing flying machines that have retracting wheels: commercial airplanes. This is such a standard feature that it is likely to reinforce, consciously or otherwise, the specific visual impression of something that flies. The DeLorean wheels don't fold away, but they do fold. I think having a flat bottom surface is likewise important for conveying the impression of "hovercraft" or "airplane," both of which have flat or flat-ish bottoms.

Third, *something* visual needs to happen when the car takes off. It can't "just" take off: it would look ungainly. Imagine if the DeLorean's wheels *didn't* somehow change. Having some kind of outward transformation occur makes the vehicle look like a flying machine. On the flipside, having the wheels simply fold sideways, rather than fold into a special receptacle, specifically could suggest that the vehicle was retrofitted, which in fact seems to be the case in all the examples brought up here.

So not only do we have visual reinforcement of

> "this thing flies"

but we also have visual reinforcement of

> "this thing used to just be a regular car, and it's been retrofitted to become a flying car. but the retrofit was efficient and smooth rather than awkward and haphazard."

This, of course, is all in addition to the apparent wheel-as-lift-generator function we see in the DeLorean, Chitty-Chitty-Bang-Bang, and the *Strange Tales* "air car" (as per the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73106/31130)).